A Cryptic Cryptic "Crossword"
This is my first time writing cryptic clues. I think I did a pretty good job of it, but I can't be sure that everything is indicated 100% properly. Sorry in advance.
I have 12 five-word cryptic clues, each indicating a five-letter word. Unfortunately, the grid they go in is... not a crossword, to say the least...

Here are the clues:


Furious rodent caught in explanation (5)
Pluck from a heartless authenticator (5)
261.6 Hertz back skin scratches (5)
Long twelve months since November (5)
Jerk headed off by magician (5)
Driven despite squishy pea head (5)
Divided into a mixed dozen (5)
Left fields rightly oafs’ domains (5)
Through stealth I effortlessly steal! (5)
Ignited helium changes to fluid (5)
Craving growth, front to back (5)
Copy twisted mineral between crosses (5)


You'll probably need to have all of the clues done before you place the words in, but looking ahead may help...
When you've filled it in properly, the solution will be some good advice.
Good luck!

I'm not sure if this question is technically an enigmatic-puzzle: the cryptic clues are that and not enigmatic, but what you do with the solutions is. If it doesn't fit, feel free to edit that tag out.

The clues can be solved like so:

 1. I(RAT)E  2. VAL(-idat)OR 3. NI(C)KS< 4. YEAR+N 5. (-t)WITCH 6. (m->P)USHY 7. ZONED* 8. FIE_ + _FS 9. _TH I EF_ 10. LIT+HE 11. (-s)URGE(+S) 12. X+ERO<+X

Note that each answer

 starts with a pentomino letter!

Using this, we can

 partition the grid into the 12 pentominoes using the letters:  

After that, we can

 Put in our words in reading order (left to right, top to bottom):

Reading the starred cells, we find that we should

 TAKE THE FIFTH, which is appropriate advice for a puzzle about pentominoes :)


Nice work! This is it!
